# What should I use on platforms pre-Kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, dataoutputstream

I am trying to send a POST to a URL and then read the response.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) registerURL.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
conn.setUseCaches(false);
try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
    wr.write(postData);
}
```

In the above, AndroidStudio warns that the line

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())
```

requires API level 19. In order to avail this to older versions, what alternative could I use? I tried searching via Google, but did not seem to find anything helpful.

Comment: Android studio is complaining because you are using `try-with-resources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing (`try-with-resources` with a regular `try` block);

```
try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
    wr.write(postData);
}
```

with

```
    DataOutputStream wr = null;

    try {
        wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postData);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(wr != null)
            try {
                wr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

This should stop AS from showing any more warnings

Comment: Thanks for your help. I sincerely appreciate it.